# How does battery protection ICs sense current

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, charging

I have a hard time grasping a concept when it comes to a particular type of battery protection ICs (which protects from overcharge/under-discharge and over-current). One example is the BQ2973 from TI, although this topology is quite common.

Link: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq2973.pdf

They all can "sense" the charge/discharge current, through a specific pin (in the case of BQ2973 the pin is called V-). I don't get how the IC can detect and categorize the current going through the battery. I see no way the current through the battery can generate some kind of voltage difference anywhere in the circuit so that the IC can measure anything related to the battery current.

In many cases there seems to be some internal circuitry with some kind of resistor between VSS and V-, but in my opinion no current would flow (at least no current proportional to the battery current) through this resistor once the transistors are fully open, as is the case when charging/discharging.

Does anyone have any experience with these kind of protection circuits?

Comment: IMO it senses the voltage drop on the output transistor.

Comment: Yes I though so as well, but it seems weird you have to find a particular transistor with particular Rds(on) to match your max battery discharge current. Could that really be the case?

Comment: The transistor is embedded in the IC, sure they now its characteristics. And this is a very rough measurement.

Comment: There are transistors embedded in the IC. There is also external transistors you have to add, which works as the main load breakers, at which VSS and V- is connected to either side. The battery current (IMO) flow mainly through theses.

Comment: looking at the linked temp/ocd accuracy graph, i wonder if the sudden  voltage drop from the battery on heavy loads is enough of a "scent" to implement OCD, and that's why cold batteries are less precise.

Comment: Apparently you have to match you external transistor Rds(on) to the threshold for overcurrent (see page 20). I didn't think measuring the drop over the transistors was reliable enough, that's why I didn't consider it. But apparently this is the way it is done, and is quite a popular method. I was looking at a Chinese that did not explain the method as obvious as TI does.